# Unable to create TextFieldTableCell when import scalafx.Includes._ is present

Tags: scala, implicit, scalafx

A following code does not compile:

```
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.application.JFXApp.PrimaryStage
import scalafx.collections.ObservableBuffer
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.control.TableColumn._
import scalafx.scene.control.{TableColumn, TableView}
import scalafx.beans.property.StringProperty
import scalafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell
import scalafx.Includes._ // remove this to compile OK

class Person(name_ : String) {

  val name = new StringProperty(this, "firstName", name_)
}
object SimpleTableView extends JFXApp {

  val characters = ObservableBuffer[Person](
    new Person("Peggy"),
    new Person("Rocky")
  )

  stage = new PrimaryStage {
    title = "Simple Table View"
    scene = new Scene {
      content = new TableView[Person](characters) {
        columns ++= List(
          new TableColumn[Person, String] {
            text = "First Name"
            cellValueFactory = {_.value.name}
            cellFactory = _ => new TextFieldTableCell[Person, String]()
            prefWidth = 180
          }
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error shown is

> Error:(31, 27) missing parameter type
>
> ```
>        cellFactory = _ => new TextFieldTableCell[Person, String]()
> ```

When I remove the `import scalafx.Includes._`, it compiles OK. This import is not needed in this example, but it is needed in my real code. The same error is shown when I do only a narrower `import scalafx.util.UtilIncludes._`.

I guess the import brings some implicit conversion into the scope, but I do not know which. Is this perhaps a bug in ScalaFx? If not, what is the reason of this error and how can I work around it?

Comment: By gradually replacing imports by importing individual members I can see the import responsible for the error is: import scalafx.util.UtilIncludes.function12jfxCallback

Comment: You can simply add a missing type:

`cell factory =  _: TableColumn[Person, String]=> new TextFieldTableCell[Person, String]()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in ScalaFX ([#236](https://github.com/scalafx/scalafx/issues/236)) that was causing the issue. It is now fixed in ScalaFX [v.8.0.92-R10](https://github.com/scalafx/scalafx/releases/tag/v8.0.92-R10). The code in the question should now compile and run without issues.